# How to append li in ul under three div ul and li?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the `li`. Here is the code:

```
<div>
    <div id="ulMenu">
        <ul id="navMainTop">
            <li>
                <a></a>
                <div>
                    <ul></ul>
                </div> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="top-menu-txt">
                    <i class="fa fa-offer"></i>Offers
                </a>
                <div class="grid-container3 blue-link" id = "serverside2">
                    <ul id= "serverside"> 
                        <!-- this one -->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

i want to get the `ul` with id "serverside" using jQuery. Here's what I am trying:

```
var mJSul = '<%=myServerSideul%>';
$("#serverside").append(mJSul.toString());
```

But this code is not working. Could someone help me figure this out?

Comment: What is the value that `mJSul` actually holds? Theoretically what you have should work fine, so long as that value is valid HTML to be placed inside a `ul` element (although you can remove the `toString()` call)

Comment: `<li> <a > links.html<./a> </li>`

Comment: In that case what you have should work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/cram9d3r/, although your `<a>` element is malformed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var mJSul = '<li><%=myServerSideul%></li>';
$("#serverside").append(mJSul);
});
```

Try this

Comment: nope problem is in getting ul that i am  not able to get even its css